# Spring: Error Button Action on Form after add registration (Spring Security)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I do an example with login page - Spring Security.

Shortly:

1. There's root page ("localhost:8080/") - here's a link on the main page.
2. Click a link on the main page go to main.html(localhost:8080/main/
3. If User doesn't authorize he is redirected to login page
4. When the user authorizes the main page is opened
5. The main page show messages and filter by tag
6. I enter a tag in input and push the button Search(Найти), messages are filtered by tag

When I have added authorization filter has stopped work.

This is my source code:

root page - have link on Main page

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Gretting start: Serving Web Content</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>Hello, user</div>
    <a th:href="@{/main}">Main page</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Main page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Введите сообщение" />
            <input type="text" name="tag" placeholder="Тэг">
            <button type="submit">Добавить</button>     
        </form>
    </div>
    <div>Список сообщений</div>
    <form method="post" action="filter">
        <input type="text" name="filter">
        <button type="submit">Найти</button>
    </form>
    <div th:each = "message : ${messages}">
        <b th:text = "${message.id}"></b>
        <span th:text = "${message.text}"></span>
        <i th:text = "${message.tag}"></i>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller processes all mapping

```
package com.example.sweater;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import com.example.sweater.domain.Message;
import com.example.sweater.repos.MessageRepo;

@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @Autowired
    private MessageRepo messageRepo;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String greeting(Model model) {

        return "greeting";

    }

    @GetMapping("/main")
    public String main(Model model) {

        Iterable<Message> messages = messageRepo.findAll();

        model.addAttribute("messages", messages);

        return "main";
    }

    @PostMapping("/main")
    public String add(@RequestParam String text, @RequestParam String tag, Model model) {

        Message message = new Message(text, tag);

        messageRepo.save(message);

        Iterable<Message> messages = messageRepo.findAll();

        model.addAttribute("messages", messages);

        return "main";
    }

    @PostMapping("/filter")
    public String filter(@RequestParam String filter, Model model) {

        Iterable<Message> messages;

        if (filter != null && !filter.isEmpty()) {
            messages = messageRepo.findByTag(filter);
        } else {
            messages = messageRepo.findAll();
        }

        model.addAttribute("messages", messages);

        return "main";

    }
}
```

WebSecurityConfig have one In Memory User. antMathcers("/") permitAll and anyRequest authenticated

```
package com.example.sweater.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user =
             User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("u")
                .password("p")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
}
```

My screenshots
root page

[image]

Main page

[image]

When I enter filter tag and push Button "Найти"(= Search), I've got an error:

[image]

`@PostMapping("/filter")` doesn't catch the action in the form. I checked in the debugger. I can't catch an error and don't know why does this happen.

I have GitHub repository: https://github.com/aalopatin/sweater

Commit with the comment "Add messages" - filter work

Commit with the comment "Add remote repository and Login" - filter doesn't work and add login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solving. In a form on the main page need to add 'th' attribute because I use Thymeleaf so template engine. It's needed for _csrf defending which auto insert token in a form if you use Thymeleaf:

```
<form method="post" th:action="filter">
   <input type="text" name="filter">
   <button type="submit">Найти</button>
</form>
```